# Add groovy.yaml.* to Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml

How can I add the groovy.yaml.* to my jenkins pipeline? I put it in my jekins pipeline,

```
@Library("shared-yaml")
import groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder
def yamlOne = new YamlBuilder()
```

Keep getting error,

```
unable to resolve class groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder
```

Thanks,
Ric

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder` in the Jenkins pipeline, because it runs on Groovy 2.4.12, and the `YamlBuilder` was introduced in Groovy 3.0.0

Comment: So the idea is to upgrade groovy 300 right?

Comment: The plugin that determines the Groovy version in the pipeline runtime is the Job DSL plugin - https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin. I don't know if there are any plans to upgrade Groovy to the newer version, you would have to ask the maintainers of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best solution,

Just use readYAML/writeYAML all along which is a Jenkins plugin not a groovy library.